# Sortable element stay after remove()

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list with sortable elements which can be deleted if you drop them into a thrash bin.
The problem is that the element stays after removing it.

```
<div class="content-remove" id="content-remove"></div>
<div class="content-elements" id="content-elements">
  <div class="element-item">
  </div>
</div>


$("#content-remove").droppable({
        accept: '#menu-contents .element-item',
        activeClass: 'active-remove',
        hoverClass: 'active-hover-remove',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
             ui.draggable.css({border: '2px solid #E64746', opacity: '0.7'});                 
             ui.droppable.css({border: '2px solid #E64746', opacity: '0.7'});
            },
        out: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.css({border: '1px solid #ccc', opacity: '1'});
            ui.droppable.css({border: '1px solid #ccc', opacity: '1'});
            }
        });
$("#menu-contents .content-elements").sortable({placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder'}).disableSelection();
```

[image: After deleting]

As you can see in the thumb, there are two placeholders but only one element. How can I solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Most probably because you have a JS error and it cannot finish the drop process. Check the console.

Comment: That's it, I tried to access the element after I remove it xD

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're removing the `ui.draggable` and not the original element. You may want to try something like:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    $("#" + id).remove();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error. After removing the element, I tried to access .css method; that produced an error and crashes the rest.